# What is a non-local state?

Tags: quantum-state, non-locality

The notion of entangled states is very neat, it simply means non-separability of the states. Another important class of states that one often hears is the non-local state. But when do we say that a state $\rho$ is nonlocal?

Comment: Can you give references? I don't think terminology here (i.e. "nonlocal state") is entirely standardized.

Answer (score 2):

The term "non-local states" most likely refers to states which allow to violate a Bell inequality. They give rise to statistics that cannot be explained with a local hidden variable model.